# How to convert sql query mysql using criteriaquery

Tags: spring, jpa, jpql

How to convert sql query mysql using criteriaquery this code:

```
SELECT  a.customer as customer,  a.cbgroup, a.cbdept, a.buc, a.customer_group, a.product, a.valuta,  a.a_amount, a.cbgroup, b.b_amount, (b.b_amount-a.a_amount) as percentage 
        FROM (
            SELECT a.customer, a.date, a.cbgroup, a.cbdept, a.buc, a.customer_group, a.product, a.valuta,  SUM(a.amount) as a_amount FROM summaryfee as a WHERE a.date = '2019-06-30' AND a.cbgroup = 'CORPORATE BANKING 1' GROUP BY a.customer
            ) AS a INNER JOIN 
            (
            SELECT b.customer, SUM(b.amount) as b_amount FROM summaryfee as b WHERE b.date = '2020-06-30' AND b.cbgroup = 'CORPORATE BANKING 1' GROUP BY b.customer
            ) AS b
        ON a.customer=b.customer  AND (b.b_amount-a.a_amount) < 0 ORDER BY CASE WHEN a.customer NOT LIKE '%Transaksi Nasabah%' THEN 0
      ELSE 1
     END, percentage asc LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite a JPQL query as a criteria query, but not any native SQL query.

The problem at a glance with your query above is that uses subqueries in FROM clause.

JPQL query language and criteria query at least up to 2.1 JPA spec, support subqueries only in WHERE and HAVING clauses.